# ORA-00937: групповая функция не является одногруппной

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть задание:

> Выбрать сотрудников у которых фамилия или имя короче 5 символов. Упорядочить записи по суммарной длине фамилии и имени, затем по длине фамилии, затем просто по фамилии, затем просто по имени.

Я пишу следующий запрос:

```
select * from EMPLOYEES e
WHERE LENGTH(e.LAST_NAME)<5 
OR LENGTH(e.FIRST_NAME)<5 
order by 
 SUM(LENGTH(e.LAST_NAME)+LENGTH(e.FIRST_NAME)) 
--LENGTH(e.LAST_NAME),e.LAST_NAME,e.FIRST_NAME;
```

И у меня возникает следующая ошибка:

> ORA-00937: групповая функция не является одногруппной.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: А что делает (точнее, нафига понадобилась) функция SUM()?

Answer (score 2):

Так в чём же причина ошибки (или заблуждение автора вопроса).

Оператор суммирования `+` выполнется для значений колонок или выражений полученных из *одной записи* (по горизонтали). Групповая функция `SUM()` выполнется для значений колонок или выражений *всех записей группы* (по вертикали), а группа без клаузы `GROUP BY` это всегда все записи полученные после условия фильтрации в `WHERE`.

То есть, на таких тестовых данных, после простейшего запроса:

```
create table t (id, fname, lname) as
    select 1, 'aaa', 'bbb' from dual union all 
    select 2, 'cc',  'dd'  from dual
/
select sum (length (fname) + length (lname))
from t
```

автор вопроса ожидал бы получить две записи со значениями 6 и 4, однако результат:

```
       SUM
----------
        10
```

Но интересен же результат для каждой записи со своим `ID` (или другими столбцами):

```
select id, sum (length (fname) + length (lname)) sumlen
from t
```

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

В этом случае БД должна вывести все `ID`, то есть, так получится несколько групп записей.
Об этом и говорится в сообщении об ошибке - групповая функция может посчитать значения только одной группы, но никак не нескольких.

Решение очевидно - групповая функция `SUM` в запросе явно лишняя:

```
select *
from t
order by (length (fname) + length (lname));

        ID FNA LNA
---------- --- ---
         2 cc  dd 
         1 aaa bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно было убрать SUM и всё получилось